# Capture http request in a callback php

Tags: php, http

I'm trying to capture http request that occurs in a callback function :

```
// Code omitted
public function capture($fn)
{
  // start http capture
  $fn();
  // end http capture and stores the capture in a variable
}


//example usage
$request->capture(function(){
  do_some_http_request_with_curl_or_whatever_you_want();
});
```

I have tried various things with ob_start() and php wrappers... But nothing works, Help would be much appreciated !

Comment: Do you want this request to run asynchronously, so you can do many requests in parallel?

Comment: No I just need to capture one request and it has to be synchronous

Comment: I doubt if you could do it without (IMO) OS/library support...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its impossible to capture any arbitrary HTTP request since the callback has lots of possible ways to go about it:

- high-level functions with URL wrappers (e.g. `file_get_contents`)
- more low-level approaches (e.g. stream, sockets)
- custom PHP extensions (e.g. curl)

Each of these approaches has (or does *not* have at all!) different ways of allowing you to hook into the mechanics of the request, so unless all mechanisms that you want to target support hooking *and* the callback actively cooperates with you, there's no way to do this.

Comment: Ok thx for the clarification, I was afraid of such answer... Will figure out an other way to do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to support stream wrappers (i.e. no socket functions used) it should be possible to unregister the `http` stream wrapper and add your own which intercepts the calls and then forwards them. Here's an example:

```
<?php

class HttpCaptureStream
{
    private $fd;
    public static $captured;

    public static function reset()
    {
        static::$captured = array();
    }

    public function stream_open($path, $mode, $options, &$opened_path)
    {
        static::$captured[] = $path;

        $this->fd = $this->restored(function () use ($path, $mode) {
            return fopen($path, $mode);
        });

        return (bool) $this->fd;
    }

    public function stream_read($count)
    {
        return fread($this->fd, $count);
    }

    public function stream_write($data)
    {
        return fwrite($this->fd, $data);
    }

    public function stream_tell()
    {
        return ftell($this->fd);
    }

    public function stream_eof()
    {
        return feof($this->fd);
    }

    public function stream_seek($offset, $whence)
    {
        return fseek($this->fd, $offset, $whence);
    }

    public function stream_stat()
    {
        return fstat($this->fd);
    }

    protected function restored($f)
    {
        stream_wrapper_restore('http');

        $result = $f();

        stream_wrapper_unregister('http');
        stream_wrapper_register('http', __CLASS__);

        return $result;
    }
}

function capture($f) {
    stream_wrapper_unregister('http');

    stream_wrapper_register('http', 'HttpCaptureStream');
    HttpCaptureStream::reset();

    $f();

    stream_wrapper_restore('http');
}

capture(function () {
    file_get_contents('http://google.com');
    file_get_contents('http://stackoverflow.com');

    var_dump(HttpCaptureStream::$captured);
});
```